# Update on Hive 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have table name 'records' with desc:

```
hive> desc records;
OK
year                    string                                      
temperature             int                                         
quality                 int
```

As per [Apache documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update) update is possible in Hive 1.2.1(versiona after 0.14.0)

I tried update command and got the error mentioned below :

```
hive> update records
    > set quality=8
    > where year='2000';
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.
```

What exactly I am missing?
Is it code or does table is not meeting any condition (limitation)?

Answer (score 1):

Update is allowed for ORC file formats only. Also you have to set few properties before performing the update or delete.

### Client Side

```
set hive.support.concurrency=true; 
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
```

### Server Side (Metastore)

```
set hive.compactor.initiator.on=true; 
set hive.compactor.worker.threads=1;
```

After setting this create the table with required properties

```
CREATE TABLE test_result
(run_id VARCHAR(100), chnl_txt_map_key INT)
clustered by (run_id) into 1 buckets 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS orc tblproperties ("transactional"="true" );
```

Now you can perform update or insert for this table. If you want the DML operations to be performed only on adhoc basis, you can set all the above properties in your session alone instead of setting the server side properties in hive-site.xml file.

Comment: Im trying on ahdoc basis, So set the config changes in the same session . But it throws the same error still.

Answer (score 0):

add in hive-site.xml the following property,

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.enforce.bucketing</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
    <value>nonstrict</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.txn.manager</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.compactor.initiator.on</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.compactor.worker.threads</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
```

and restart hive server

check this link -> http://sanjivblogs.blogspot.in/2014/12/transactions-are-available-in-hive-014.html
hope this helps