# Hive table update error Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations

Tags: hive, acid

My hive version.

```
hive --version
    Hive 1.2.0-mapr-1710
    Subversion git://cd4a097b705d/root/opensource/mapr-hive-1.2/dl/mapr-hive-1.2 -r cf159db974ca9f31211937874eef67b0105ef5cd
    Compiled by root on Mon Oct 16 20:04:27 UTC 2017
    From source with checksum 07ae5487de4e08bffbf15ebbd119411a
```

configs enabled

```
set hive.support.concurrency=true;
set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nostrict;
set hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;
set hive.compactor.worker.threads=1;
```

Table create

```
Create table test (
col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10)
)
PARTITIONED BY (col3 VARCHAR(1)) 
CLUSTERED BY (col2) SORTED BY (col2) INTO 2 BUCKETS
stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');
```

Then a simple update query is issued and got the following error.

```
update test set col2='xyz' where col2='abc';
```

Error

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.
```

hive 0.14 and later supports ACID properties. Is it right?

A am setting the changes to the current session. not in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Hive 0.14 and later versions are supporting ACID properties.
    I think, you are missing some configuration properties.
    have a look the answer [update-on-hive-1-2-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677208/update-on-hive-1-2-1)

Comment: This url also has the same steps as i have mentioned.

Comment: My curiosity, have done changes in hive-site and metastore as well. If not then can you try them out.

Comment: no actually no permission to make changesat hive-site and metastore. But i was told it is already session level available